# Ошибка в контроллере OPENCART

Tags: opencart, controller

```js
public function getRecurringDescription() {
  $this->load->language('product/product');
  $this->load->model('catalog/product');
  if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
   $product_id = $this->request->post['product_id'];
  } else {
   $product_id = 0;
  }
  if (isset($this->request->post['recurring_id'])) {
   $recurring_id = $this->request->post['recurring_id'];
  } else {
   $recurring_id = 0;
  }
  if (isset($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
   $quantity = $this->request->post['quantity'];
  } else {
   $quantity = 1;
  }
  $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
  $recurring_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProfile($product_id, $recurring_id);
  $json = array();
  if ($product_info && $recurring_info) {
   if (!$json) {
    $frequencies = array(
     'day'        => $this->language->get('text_day'),
     'week'       => $this->language->get('text_week'),
     'semi_month' => $this->language->get('text_semi_month'),
     'month'      => $this->language->get('text_month'),
     'year'       => $this->language->get('text_year'),
    );
    if ($recurring_info['trial_status'] == 1) {
     $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($recurring_info['trial_price'] * $quantity, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
     $trial_text = sprintf($this->language->get('text_trial_description'), $price, $recurring_info['trial_cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['trial_frequency']], $recurring_info['trial_duration']) . ' ';
    } else {
     $trial_text = '';
    }
    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($recurring_info['price'] * $quantity, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
    if ($recurring_info['duration']) {
     $text = $trial_text . sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_description'), $price, $recurring_info['cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['frequency']], $recurring_info['duration']);
    } else {
     $text = $trial_text . sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_cancel'), $price, $recurring_info['cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['frequency']], $recurring_info['duration']);
    }
    $json['success'] = $text;
   }
  }
  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }
}
            'price_value'=>  $option_value['price'];
           'points_value'=>  intval($option_value['points_prefix'].$option_value['points']);
```

Ошибка
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /var/www/u0230607/data/www/invird.ru/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/product/product.php on line 778

Может это быть связано с правками в этом файле product.tpl которые были здесь:

```js
 <!-- ЦЕНА И КНОПКА ЗАКАЗА - НАЧАЛО -->
                    <?php if ($price) { ?>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <?php if (!$special) { ?>
                                <li class="price-left">
                                    <h2><?= $price; ?></h2>
                                </li>
                                <li class="price-right"><!-- КНОПКА ЗАКАЗА - НАЧАЛО -->
                                    <button style="height:40px;width:170px;background-color:#090; color:#FFF;border-radius:5px;border:0;" type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?= $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?= $product['minimum']; ?>');">
                                        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Добавить в корзину</span>
                                        <!--ЗНАЧОК КОРЗИНЫ<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>-->
          </button>
                                   <!-- КНОПКА ЗАКАЗА - КОНЕЦ --></li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <li class="price-left">
                                    <h2><?= $special; ?></h2>
                                </li>
                                <li class="price-right">
         <span class="through"><?= $price; ?></span>
         <div class="econ">Экономия: <span class="econ-value"><?= $econ; ?></span></div>
        </li>
                                <li class="price-right"><!-- КНОПКА ЗАКАЗА - НАЧАЛО -->
                                    <button style="height:40px;width:170px;background-color:#090; color:#FFF;border-radius:5px;border:0;" type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?= $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?= $product['minimum']; ?>');">
                                        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Добавить в корзину</span>
                                        <!--ЗНАЧОК КОРЗИНЫ<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>-->
          </button>
                                   <!-- КНОПКА ЗАКАЗА - КОНЕЦ --></li>
```

Comment: Какая версия opencart ?

Comment: Версия 2.3.0.2.1

Comment: Видимо вы какой то плагин установили?

Answer (score 0):

Представленный фрагмент кода некорректный и работать не будет.
Попробуйте удалить эти строчки:

```
'price_value'=>  $option_value['price'];
           'points_value'=>  intval($option_value['points_prefix'].$option_value['points']);
```

может они туда попали по ошибке.

Comment: Не помогло( такая же ошибка. В редакторе php шторм подчеркивает символ =>

Comment: Тут наверно не так ,что то с дополнениями

Comment: Как он может подчеркивать, если я просил удалить эти строчки?

Comment: А я взял и заменил) , удалил строчки как вы сказали ошибка исчезла но на странице товара вылазит в верху страницы новая if (!empty($_SESSION['token']) and empty($this->request->get['li_sub'])) {

Comment: Может это как то быть связано с правками в этом файле product.tpl